# Flex Chart With Custom Tick And Axis

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am using a Flex mx AreaChart and would like to customize the tick marks and axises.  I would like to use rounded rects for the ticks and axis bar, but I cant find any solutions to accomplish this.[image]

This is the design I would like to try to implement.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  Im fine using a 3rd party charting library if it can do this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Seems I had to write my own AxisRenderer.  I just had to change the drawAxis() and drawTicks() methods, but since they are private you cant just extend the class and override them, you have to copy the whole class and change those parts.